# Is the sheaf of rings $\mathscr{O}$ the sheafification of a presheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This a paragraph from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

> Next we will define a sheaf of rings $\mathscr{O}$ on $\text{Spec }A$. 
>   For each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$, 
>   let $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$. 
>   For an open set $U\subseteq \text{Spec }A$, 
>   we define $\mathscr{O}(U)$ to be the set of functions $s:U\to \coprod_{\mathfrak{p}\in U}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, 
>   such that $s(\mathfrak{p})\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for each $\mathfrak{p}$, 
>   and such that $s$ is locally a quotient of elements of $A$:
>   to be precise, 
>   we require that for each $\mathfrak{p}\in U$, 
>   there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathfrak{p}$, 
>   contained in $U$, 
>   and elements $a, f\in A$, 
>   such that for each $\mathfrak{q}\in V$, $f\notin \mathfrak{q}$, 
>   and $s(\mathfrak{q})=a/f$ in $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$. 
>   (Note the the similarity with the definition of the regular functions on a variety. 
>   The difference is that we consider functions into the various local rings, 
>   instead of to a field.)

**My Question:**
$\mathscr{O}$ seems to be the sheafification of a presheaf. Is it? What is it?

I have compared the construction of the sheafification of a presheaf:

> We construct the sheaf $\mathscr{F}^+$ as follows. 
>   For any open set $U$, 
>   let $\mathscr{F}^+(U)$ be the set of functions $s$ from $U$ to the union $\bigcup_{P\in U}\mathscr{F}_P$ of the stalks of $\mathscr{F}$ over points of $U$, 
>   such that
>
> (1) for each $P\in U$, $s(P)\in \mathscr{F}_P$, and
>
> (2) for each $P\in U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $P$, 
>   contained in $U$, 
>   and an element $t\in \mathscr{F}(V)$, 
>   such that for all $Q\in V$, 
>   the germ $t_Q$ of $t$ at $Q$ is equal to $s(Q)$.

I think it should have
$$\varinjlim_{\mathfrak{p}\in U}\mathscr{F}(U)=\mathscr{F}_{\mathfrak{p}}=A_{\mathfrak{p}}=\varinjlim_{f\in A\backslash \mathfrak{p}}A_f. $$
But I don't know how to defin $\mathscr{F}(U)$...

**Edit.**
I know that every sheaf is a presheaf itself. 
However, 
we have not proven that $\mathscr{O}$ is a sheaf. 
It is the task of the following paragraph in the book.

> Now it is clear that sums and products of such funtions are again such, 
>   and that the element $1$ which gives $1$ in each $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an identity. 
>   Thus $\mathscr{O}(U)$ is a commutative ring with identity. 
>   If $V\subseteq U$ are two open sets, 
>   the natural restriction map $\mathscr{O}(U)\to \mathscr{O}(V)$ is a homomorphism of rings. 
>   It is then clear that $\mathscr{O}$ is a presheaf. 
>   Finally, it is clear from the local nature of the definition that $\mathscr{O}$ is a sheaf.

That is why I am looking for a presheaf which induces $\mathscr{O}$.

Comment: Every sheaf is a presheaf, and is the sheafification of itself.

Comment: Yes: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80548/affine-scheme-on-speca-of-a-ring-a-as-the-sheafification-of-a-pre-sheave-on-sp/80560#80560